# Can I log onto an existing Tribes: Ascend account through Steam?

Tags: steam, tribes-ascend

Before Tribes: Ascend was added to Steam, I created an account and bought some items/upgrades.  If I download Tribes through Steam, will I be able to log into my existing account or link my Steam account with it, or would I be forced to repurchase the items and upgrades on my Steam account?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The assumption from this [article](http://pc.gamespy.com/pc/tribes-ascend/1225241p1.html) is that you'll be able to tether your existing account to your Steam account. I'm not 100% sure as I personally don't play Tribes. However, my experience with Borderlands (which is also run by GameSpy) tells me that you'll be able to link your account.

Comment: This is indeed the case.  My download just finished, and the game presents the same login screen when launched through steam.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you will be able to; I've done it.

The Steam version of Tribes still uses the HR authentication.