# Activate Tribes Ascend starter pack bought on Steam

Tags: steam, tribes-ascend

I've bought the [starter pack](http://store.steampowered.com/app/17095/) for Tribes: Ascend on Steam but am unable to activate it in game.

My Tribes account is a non-steam account created a while ago, can I link it to Steam somehow?

Comment: Were you sent a promo code?

Comment: Not as far as I'm aware, any idea how I would check that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will put the starter pack on the first account you login to from the steam version of the game, so you have to download it from steam and login there to get it, but after that you can go back to using the hirez launcher in you want.

Comment: This is correct. All Tribes:Ascend accounts are non Steam. Launching the game from within Steam will just launch the HiRez launcher, however for Steam purchases you'll need to launch via Steam. See http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/75310/can-i-log-onto-an-existing-tribes-ascend-account-through-steam

Comment: I did start from steam actually.. I've got it now, just took a couple of days after I bought it to show up for some reason.

Comment: Would be nice to avoid having to download the game again in Steam... any ways to start the download, close Steam and then copy the files over from the other install location ?